# Render HTML that is saved in and returned from Backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a project where I get back a string from the backend, that contains some html. I'd now like to put this html into `gatsby`:

```
let htmlFromBackend = `<b>Hello there</b>, partner!`

return (
  <div>
   {htmlFromBackend}
  </div>
)
```

However, this prints out the html as plain text, so what I see on the screen is literally:

```
<b> Hello there</b>, partner!
```

Whereas it should be

> **Hello there**, partner!

How can I render this as proper html?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) however be sure you trust the data coming from the backend as you don't get any protection from [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).

```js
let htmlFromBackend = `<b>Hello there</b>, partner!`

return (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlFromBackend }} />
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `useRef` hook and set the element's `innerHTML`:

```
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let htmlFromBackend = `<b>Hello there</b>, partner!`;
    ref.current.innerHTML = htmlFromBackend;
  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install html-react-parser**

```
npm i html-react-parser;
```

**And in the component**

```
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';

let htmlFromBackend = `<b>Hello there</b>, partner!`

return (
  <div>
   {Parser((htmlFromBackend)}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. is there an advantage using `html-react-parser` over `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (the other answer) ?

Comment: don't see any reason to use an additional package in your case, moreover it is a parser and not only dom parser, but react parser - a huge overkill imho. And `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` just puts your html inside a div, just as needed

Comment: I think you'd only want to use html-react-parser if you wanted to render custom components (e.g. instead of <button /> you want to render your own <Button /> component with custom styles / state / behaviour). For just rendering plain HTML I would agree html-react-parser is overkill.