# Rendering html response from API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render an html response from an API in React.

I think the problem can be that I am not handling the async fetch correctly. I am not sure if the html string I am fetching from the BE is a promise or a string. When I log it below I get a `Promise`

I used the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66076745/4755832) to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render the html though I am not sure if this is the right way to render a complete page. The backendHtmlString is a complete page that I would just like to add to React.

`App.js` - React code to render html:

```js
async function createMarkup() {
  let response;
  response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/backed_api/html_response/?user_email=chriss%40comtura.ai`)
  const backendHtmlString = response.text()

  console.log(backendHtmlString)
  return {__html: backendHtmlString};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Index.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Store the html in a useState field after receiving it, and use a useEffect callback to send the request. Currently you're sending the request on every single render...

Comment: You need to `await` the `response.text()` call to get the actual response text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async functions always return a `Promise`! Make sure you **resolve** it to get the data.

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Since, the data is fetched from the backend, it may take some time. You can use `useEffect` to make the request and set the value you get from the server using `useState`.

```jsx
function MyComponent() {
    
      const [html, setHTML] = useState({__html: ""});
    
      useEffect(() => {
        async function createMarkup() {
          let response;
          response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/backed_api/html_response/?user_email=chriss%40comtura.ai`)
           const backendHtmlString = await response.text()
    
           console.log(backendHtmlString)
            return {__html: backendHtmlString};
         }
         createMarkup().then(result => setHTML(result));
      }, []);
      
    
      return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html} />;
    }
```

Also, check out this [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71140922/11566161). It could be another case  similar to yours.

Comment: In my case, API response an HTML page, with a lot of links (jquery, other packages) . dangerouslySetInnerHTML can not load the jQuery and other scripts, what should i do?

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML will not work well in this case.

You should either 
- make API to respond the list of scripts and inject it using useScripts or react-helmet.
- or parse HTML in the response and extract script tags and do the first one.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64815699/11566161

Comment: can i write the response in a .html file on the fly and store it in public folder , then render it on iframe ?

Comment: Yes, not sure if any other way there.. :(